# How to interact with ActiveDirectory server?

Tags: active-directory, python-3.x

I am want to write an application that interact with an ActiveDirectory server (the server that the client who run the program is authenticated with), specifically i need to change AD user's password through the application.

I have tinkered with pywin32, but i am don't sure it give me the ability to change things, just to retrieve already configured options.

Is anyone knows about a module or any other feature that would let me do that ?

I have found [this](https://github.com/dfwarden/ActiveDirectory-Python), but it is seem to be an experiment, is there something more standardize ?

as i have mentioned i know Java too, and i could write that program with Java although i not prefer to do so, but in case i have to, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The active_directory module supports Python 3: https://github.com/tjguk/active_directory